# Open Android Auto car app from the mobile app

Tags: android, android-auto

How to open the Android Auto car app from the mobile app?

I want to open the car app in the Desktop Head Unit when a button on the mobile app Activity is clicked.

Tried starting the CarAppService class but the onCreateSession(...) is not getting called.

Answer (score 1):

The mobile app has your own main activity as a launch activity, however, Android Auto has not. I suppose that you need to have one module working for mobile and one for Android Auto. Then you run different modules for mobile and Android Auto in your project.

Comment: If possible can you give a code sample on how to start the car app from the mobile app. Car app doesn't have an activities right? The car app UI extends Screen class.

Comment: Yes car app doesn't have activities. Did you find a solution? I am also looking for a way to update the cap app from the mobile app...

Comment: You can try to check this solution https://medium.com/@loicteyssier/bring-your-android-app-into-your-car-part-2-cafe-finder-android-auto-app-7a8063b098e2